# jquery find and replace input field is replacing all of my content not just individual paragraphs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have some paragraphs and an input box. Basically the user types into the field, and when they press "ENTER" it runs the jquery function seen a bit further down.

Essentially what happens is, when a match is found between the paragraph and the user input, the HTML of the paragraph is, for want of a better phrase, *replaced by itself* but this time round with a span wrapped round the matching text for the purpose of CSS to highlight it.

That's great, but the problem I'm having is that when the text is replaced, it replaces is with every single HTML element of that type on the page. Kind of hard to put into words so have a look at the behaviour with this fiddle. Enter in some text that is obviously appearing in the paragraph and see what it does.

How can I make the text regenerate element by element rather than taking everything in the world and reproducing it?

```
<input type="text" id="searchbox">
<p>Let's get some text to test</p>
<p>This is another paragraph</p>

function searchHighlight(searchText){
    if(searchText){
        // Declare variable for the question content
        var content = $('p').text();

        // Declare variable for the search phrase
        var searchExp = new RegExp(searchText, "ig");

        // Declare a variable for when a match is found
        var matches = content.match(searchExp);

        // If some of the text is found in the QUESTION do the following...
        if(matches){
            $("p").html(content.replace(searchExp, function(match){
                return "<span class='selected'>" + match + "</span>";
        }))
    }
    else{
        $("#searchbox").css("border", "1px solid red")
    }
}
```

Here is a fiddle
https://jsfiddle.net/awv5r1f0/1/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To achieve expected result , use below option using each, to find search the word and replace that particular p html

**Issue:** `$("p").html()` will update all p tags which is replace all of your p tags with same text

1. Update with looping all p elements
2. Using $(this).html update only p element with that matching word

```
$("p").each(function() {
    $(this).html($(this).text().replace(searchExp, function(match) {
        return "<span class='selected'>" + match + "</span>";
    }))
})
```

[code sample](https://codepen.io/nagasai/pen/gNgLza)

```js
$(function() {
    // Create event for enter key in searchbox
    $("#searchbox").on("keydown", function(event) {
        if (event.which == 13) {
            // run function
            searchHighlight($(this).val())
        }
    })
})

function searchHighlight(searchText) {
    if (searchText) {
        // Declare variable for the question content
        var content = $('p').text();

        // Declare variable for the search phrase
        var searchExp = new RegExp(searchText, "ig");

        // Declare a variable for when a match is found
        var matches = content.match(searchExp);

        // If some of the text is found in the QUESTION do the following...
        if (matches) {
            $("p").each(function() {
                $(this).html($(this).text().replace(searchExp, function(match) {
                    return "<span class='selected'>" + match + "</span>";
                }))
            })
        } else {
            $("#searchbox").css("border", "1px solid red")
        }
    }
}
```

```css
.selected{
  background: yellow;
  font-weight: 700;
}
#searchbox{
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  outline: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="searchbox">
<p>Let's get some text to test</p>
<p>This is another paragraph</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure this is the best solution but it does what you requested.
The problem was that you were changing the `html` of every `p` you have. Not only for the one where the word was matched.

I used an `each` method to search through all the `p` you have. And insert the span where the match was found. This would work even if you have a bunch of questions (`p`) that have the match.

See below

```js
$(function() {
  // Create event for enter key in searchbox
  $("#searchbox").on("keydown", function(event) {
    if (event.which == 13) {
      // run function
      searchHighlight($(this).val())
    }
  })
})

function searchHighlight(searchText) {
  if (searchText) {
    // Declare variable for the question content
    var content = $('p').text();

    // Declare variable for the search phrase
    var searchExp = new RegExp(searchText, "ig");

    // Declare a variable for when a match is found
    var matches = content.match(searchExp);

    // If some of the text is found in the QUESTION do the following...
    $('p').each(function() {
      if ($(this).text().match(searchExp)) {
        $(this).html($(this).html().replace(searchExp, function(match) {
          return "<span class='selected'>" + match + "</span>";
        }))
      } else {
        $("#searchbox").css("border", "1px solid red")
      }
    })
  }
}
```

```css
.selected {
  background: yellow;
  font-weight: 700;
}

#searchbox {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  outline: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="searchbox">
<p>Let's get some text to test</p>
<p>This is another paragraph</p>
```